# Request Django Template using Ajax

Tags: javascript, django

I have a Django template that contains some Django templating blocks. I have another template that contains some JavaScript that does an Ajax request to pull this Django template in. It looks something like this:

```
$.ajax({
    url: '/page/',
    method: 'GET',
    success: function (data) {
        console.log($(data).find(".wrapper"));
    }
});
```

`/page.html/` contains the following:

```
{% extends 'core/base.html' %}
{% block content %}
   <div class="example">
      ..some..content..
   </div>
{% endblock %}
```

`page.html` extends `base.html` which has a wrapper `<div class="wrapper"></div>` however, when I run the Ajax code, the console does not find the wrapper class. Is there a way to get the full template page?

**Example of raw data to console output**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
   <head>
      <link href="/static/core/patterns.css?1587877907" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
   </head>
   <body>
      <div class="wrapper">
         <div class="jumbotron jumbotron-gray">
            <article class="post" data-key="294" data-slug="example">
               <div class="post__details">Example</div>
            </article>
         </div>
      </div>
      <script src="/static/core/base.js?1587877907"></script>
   </body>
</html>
```

Comment: If you log just `data` what does it return?

Comment: @IainShelvington length = 0, there's nothing that exists that contains the class called wrapper. However, when I do something like this `$(body).html(data);` then everything will update and it'll show the wrapper and everything.

Comment: What is the raw value of `data`? Can you share what the returned html looks like?

Comment: @IainShelvington Sure, updated the question